# RAD Studio IDE Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: delphi, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, c++builder, breakpoints

I just spent 15 minutes looking for a list of default IDE keyboard shortcuts because I went completely blank on how to toggle a breakpoint using a keyboard shortcut- was driving my nuts.

If anyone can find a page in the XE3 documentation wiki, I'd love to see it.

Comment: I mean, it's gotta exist in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you believe I couldn't find this in the XE3 documentation wiki; I ended up with this page after a bit of googling:

http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys

(F5 btw,to toggle breakpoints < headslap />).

Hope it helps someone.